# Setup project in c# windows application cant load image?

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

![enter image description here][1]i have a windows application in C# with a setup project !!!
I used `Image.FromFile("filename")` in my application but when make a setup project from it , and run it , it dose not show my pictures ! why ?

```
try
            {
                string timeOfDay = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Substring(3, 2)).ToString();
                this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("BackGround\\Flowers (" + timeOfDay + ").jpg");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("\\BackGround\\Flowers (59).jpg");

            }
```

Comment: People can't answer your question with this much information. Please provide more..

Comment: Check the Build Action of that image file under image properties, Make it Resource and try

Comment: @AccessDenied how can i done this ? the images are in a folder in bin folder

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add the Image file to your Visual Studio project unless you do this image can not be embedded into the output assembly.

Project Folder > Images

First add a custom folder and move your image to that folder and add the same folder to your VS project. now go to Image property and set the Build Action as "Resource".

Comment: @Mina Can you show where you added that folder to VS project and the path you are using to refer that image ?

Comment: i added code to question . it works correctly in application but it dosnt work in exe version

Comment: @Mina So did you add a folder to your project called BackGround ? and moved the images there ?